# Cannot see the text content on using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Please take a look at the code sample

I am trying to render a hamburger icon and a menu that appears when a user hovers over the menu icon. Surprisingly, though you can see a menu, the text is missing.

Although, if I remove `display: flex` from `.menu`, everything seems to work fine. I am unsure as to how the flexbox is affecting the text content.

```css
/*
  Author: Rahul Shetty
*/

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body *,
body *::after,
body *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Header */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
header {
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(12, 13, 14, 0.1), 0 1px 6px rgba(59, 64, 69, 0.1);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fafafb;
  transition: box-shadow cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.25s;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-top: 3px solid #f48024;
}

.logo-hamburger {
  display: flex;
}

.menu {
  width: 44px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.menu:hover {
  background-color: #eff0f1;
}

.hamburger-icon {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #848d95;
}

.hamburger-icon::after,
.hamburger-icon::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  background: #848d95;
  top: -5px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.1s;
}

.hamburger-icon::after {
  top: 5px;
}

.hambuger-menu {
  width: 240px;
  display: none;
  top: 47px;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  color: #2f3337;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(12, 13, 14, 0.2);
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  border-left: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
  border-right: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
}

.menu:hover .hambuger-menu {
  display: block;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Main */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
main {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.block-title {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Footer */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

```html
    <header>
      <div class="logo-hamburger">
        <div class="menu">
          <span class="hamburger-icon"></span>

          <nav class="hambuger-menu">
            <ul>
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Home</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item">
                <a href="#" class="menu-link">Public</a>
              </li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Teams</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>

        <a href="#" class="logo-link">Stack Overflow</a>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: The text is off-screen to the left. Just inspect the elements.

Comment: When I removed the position absolute from your `.hambuger-menu` the links appeared. Have you checked if it's a positioning or a z-index issue?

Comment: @MihailMinkov The text is a part of the absolutely positioned container. If it was an issue related to z-index, the container itself should have been hidden and not just the text. No?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Aah! That was correct. Adding `left: 0` fixed it.

Comment: `left: 0` is overriding the menu `justify-content: center` looks like a hack to me as you are using flex + justify-content only to center your hamburger icon.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code.

```css
/*
  Author: Rahul Shetty
*/

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body *,
body *::after,
body *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Header */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
header {
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(12, 13, 14, 0.1), 0 1px 6px rgba(59, 64, 69, 0.1);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fafafb;
  transition: box-shadow cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.25s;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-top: 3px solid #f48024;
}

.logo-hamburger {
  display: flex;
}

.menu {
  width: 44px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}

.menu:hover {
  background-color: #eff0f1;
}

.hamburger-icon {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #848d95;
  align-self: center;
}

.hamburger-icon::after,
.hamburger-icon::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  background: #848d95;
  top: -5px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.1s;
}

.hamburger-icon::after {
  top: 5px;
}

.hambuger-menu {
  width: 240px;
  display: none;
  top: 47px;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  color: #2f3337;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(12, 13, 14, 0.2);
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  border-left: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
  border-right: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
  
}

.menu:hover .hambuger-menu {
  display: block;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Main */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
main {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.block-title {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Footer */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

```html
<header>
<div class="logo-hamburger">
<div class="menu">
<span class="hamburger-icon"></span>

<nav class="hambuger-menu">
<ul>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Home</a></li>
<li class="menu-item">
<a href="#" class="menu-link">Public</a>
</li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link">Teams</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>

<a href="#" class="logo-link">Stack Overflow</a>
</div>
</header>
```